# How do I save a Text file on the Universal Windows Platform?

Tags: c#, uwp

I'm trying to save my text file in UWP, but It always saving to different file. By the way I'm using MVVM architecture.

My Code

```cs
FileSavePicker savePicker = new FileSavePicker();
savePicker.SuggestedFileName = "New Text Document";
savePicker.SuggestedStartLocation = PickerLocationId.Desktop;
savePicker.FileTypeChoices.Add("Text Document", new List<string>() { ".txt" });
savePicker.DefaultFileExtension = ".txt";

StorageFile storageFile = await savePicker.PickSaveFileAsync();
if(storageFile != null)
{
        CachedFileManager.DeferUpdates(storageFile);
        await FileIO.WriteTextAsync(storageFile, Document.Text);
        FileUpdateStatus updateStatus = await CachedFileManager.CompleteUpdatesAsync(storageFile);
        Document.FileName = savePicker.SuggestedFileName;                   
        Document.IsSaved = true;
}
```

My code is always saving texts on different file. I'm trying to save my text to same file.

Comment: I don't really understand your problem, you show a filepicker and pick a specific file. Then the text gets writte to that file. Where exactly is the problem?

Comment: Could you please share more details about your question? I tired your code, it's try to create a new file and write content from the `Document` object.

Are you trying to save text to the same file multiple times?

Comment: @RoyLi-MSFT yes I'm trying to save text to the same file multiple times. By the way sorry for my English.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In UWP there is a feature called [FutureAccessList](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.storage.accesscache.storageapplicationpermissions?view=winrt-22621). It can be used to save the token of the file, opened with the FilePicker. When you now want to save it again you can retrive the StorageFile by the token and write to it.

Add a FileToken property to your Document class:

```
public string FileToken { get; set; }
```

Now when you pick your file you add the file to the FutureAccessList:

```
...
StorageFile storageFile = await savePicker.PickSaveFileAsync();
if (storageFile != null)
{
    CachedFileManager.DeferUpdates(storageFile);
    await FileIO.WriteTextAsync(storageFile, Document.Text);
    FileUpdateStatus updateStatus = await CachedFileManager.CompleteUpdatesAsync(storageFile);
    Document.FileName = savePicker.SuggestedFileName;
    Document.IsSaved = true;

    //Add the file to the FutureAccessList to get it back later
    Document.FileToken = StorageApplicationPermissions.FutureAccessList.Add(storageFile);
}
```

To retrive the file and save it again:

```
public async void SaveFile()
{
    //Get the file back from the FutureAccessList by its token and write to it
    StorageFile file = await StorageApplicationPermissions.FutureAccessList.GetFileAsync(Document.FileToken);
    await FileIO.WriteTextAsync(file, Document.Text);
}
```

Now when you e.g. save your Document class to Json and retrive it after the app restarts you can still use the FileToken to write to the file. There is no need to let the user pick it again using the SaveFilePicker.

---

When the code above is to complicated or there is no need for this (I don't know what you need this for), you can put a StorageFile propertie directly to your Document class and put the file, that the SaveFilePicker returned in it. But this won't work when restarting the app. The user would always have to pick the file again.

Comment: Thank you so much. I worked on this issue for a week. You resolved this issue immediately. Thanks again.